# jQuery accordion links do not work

Tags: jquery, accordion, toggle, hyperlink

I have no idea what I am doing, but I found some code, that I am using to create a accordion dropdown for a help page on my blog.
Everything is working perfectly, but when I click on a link in the dropdown, it closes the accordion and does not go to the external site. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Is there a way to fix this?

Here is the code I am using...

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("li.profile a").click(function(e) {
   jQuery(e.target).closest("li").find("p").toggle();
    return false;
    })
```

});

This is the html...

```
<ul >
   <li class="profile">
      <a href="#">Section 1</a>
      <p style="display: none;">
      <a href="www.google.com">Click here</a> Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
  ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
  amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
  odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

If there is a fix for this, please dumb it down for me so I will understand what I need to do.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("li.profile > a").click(function(e) {
   jQuery(e.target).closest("li").find("p").toggle();
    return false;
    })
});
```